# ordered field $\implies$ $0$ cannot be written as the sum of two squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

I recently read in a forum post that "a necessary condition for a field to be ordered is that the number zero cannot be written as the sum of two squares". What does this mean? Why is this a necessary condition? What does the ability of two squares to sum to zero have to do with a field being ordered?

Comment: Well, the statement needs to be qualified somehow: $0^2 + 0^2 = 0$, obviously. A more accurate statement would be: If $0 = x^2+y^2$ with $x$ and $y$ elements of an ordered field, then $x=y=0$. When you see the phrase "ordered field", think of the real numbers. That might help you with your intuition.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein am I correct in thinking that an ordered field is a field where there is a clear definition for the $<$ and $>$ operators? So the field of complex numbers is unordered, as you can't say that, say, $z_1 > z_2$, only that (maybe) $|z_1| > |z_2|$?

Comment: You should look up [the definition of an ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Positive_cone), if you're not already familiar with it. I'm partial to the positive cone definition, which is the one I've linked you to there.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, an ordered field isn't just a field with an ordering... it is a field with an ordering *that respects the field's operations*.

In particular: it must be the case that for any $a\in F$, $a^2\geq 0$.

Now, for any $a,b\neq0$, we must have $a^2>0$ and $b^2>0$; so, $a^2+b^2>0$.

Comment: For context, the poster claimed that the field of complex numbers is not ordered, since $1^2 + i^2 = 0$. Wouldn't it have been simpler to just say that $i^2 < 0$, so by your first inequality, the field is not ordered? Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @Bluefire How about a possible order in which $-1>0$? In this case, $i^2$ alone says nothing.